# How to obtain average data from multiple dynamic table rows created in Android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, multiple-columns, rows, android-tablelayout

I'm still a beginner in Android development and I'm developing a timer app with Start/stop toggle button creates table row. My big problem is what do I do to get an average from the multiple table rows created with lets say Columns a(tvLeft),b(tvCenter) and c(tvRight). Your Help with either a tutorial or advice will be very much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
long init, now, paused, millis, seconds, minutes, hours, elapsedMillis;
TextView display;
TextView display2;
TextView duration;
String displayLength = "------";
String displayTimeApart = "------";
String startTime = "";
String endTime;
Handler handler;
String lengthSum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    handler = new Handler();
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer2);
    final ToggleButton startContraction = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (startContraction.isChecked()) {
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                millis = now - init;
                seconds = ((millis / 1000) % 60);
                minutes = (millis / 1000) / 60;
                hours = (minutes / 3600000);
                String hh = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours + "";
                String mm = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes + "";
                String ss = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds + "";
                display.setText(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
                displayLength = ss + "s";
                String pattern = "hh:mm a";
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                try {
                    Date date = format.parse("12/31/2006");
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                endTime=(format.format(new Date())); /*display endTime*/
                handler.postDelayed(this, 30);

            } else {
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                millis = now - init;
                seconds = ((millis / 1000) % 60);
                minutes = (millis / 1000) / 60;
                hours = (minutes / 3600000);
                String hh = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours + "";
                String mm = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes + "";
                String ss = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds + "";
                display2.setText(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
                displayTimeApart =mm + "m"+ ss + "s";
                /*
                * The ENDClock starts here
                * */
                String pattern = "hh:mm a";
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                try {
                    Date date = format.parse("12/31/2006");
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startTime=(format.format(new Date()));      /*Display startTime*/
                handler.postDelayed(this, 30);           /*runs every 30Milliseconds*/
            }
        }
    };

    startContraction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            init = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.post(updater);
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.toggleButton1:
                    if (!startContraction.isChecked()) {
                        createTableRow(v);

                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    paused = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    init += System.currentTimeMillis() - paused;

}
```

//Table row is created here

```
public void createTableRow(View v) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.contraction_table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(0,2,2,0);
    tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

    TextView tvLeft = new TextView(this);
    tvLeft.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvLeft.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvLeft.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
    tvLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    tvLeft.setText(displayLength);
    TextView tvCenter = new TextView(this);
    tvCenter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvCenter.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvCenter.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);   /*(16, 15, 26, 15)*/
    tvCenter.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    tvCenter.setText(displayTimeApart);
    TextView tvRight = new TextView(this);
    tvRight.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvRight.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvRight.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tvRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    tvRight.setText(startTime + "-" + endTime);/*startTime + "-" + endTime*/

    tr.addView(tvLeft);
    tr.addView(tvCenter);
    tr.addView(tvRight);

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Table layout XML

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
      android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contraction_table"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:text="Column A"
                    android:background="#aed581"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

                    >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Column B"
                    android:background="#aed581"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    >
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Column C"
                    android:background="#aed581"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```